# Throw an exception when Mongoose document with provided Id not found in updateOne query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, exception

I'm running an `updateOne` query in Mongoose as such:

```
updateHackathonDetails(hackathonId, updatedHackathonData) {
    return Hackathon.updateOne(
        {hackathonId: hackathonId},
        {data: updatedHackathonData}
    ).exec();
}
```

When this doesn't find a document with `hackathonId`, it simply returns me:

> { n: 0, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }

Which clearly states that it couldn't modify the document because it wasn't found. Now what I want is for this query to throw an exception if a document with this Id was not found. Of course, the obvious way would be to read the `nModified` if it is 0 and throw an exception manually, but does Mongoose have an inbuilt way to do this?

Since I'm returning a promise, I should ideally just be able to catch the exception in my catch block in the calling function. I wonder if there's a way to do this using mongoose only? Without manually checking and throwing an exception?

Comment: Why should this be an exception? Is there not a clear distinction between attempt to talk to database worked and attempt to talk to database did not work? You just got a response that the operation tried to do something, did not break any rules but simply did not modify anything. So I cannot see how this can be considered an "error" and the general lack of this being treated as such would imply that the larger community agrees. So no there is no "setting" to do this, and your perspective is somewhat more towards unique than the norm.

Comment: Yes I think you are techinically correct. The reason I ask is because it would be a lot easier to simply receive an error from mongoose, get it in the catch block and forward it to the error handler using 'next'. Now that would be neat wouldn't it

Comment: Probably not. Too long an explanation to go into really but consider that `nModified != nMatched`. Which is the missing return in the exposed mongoose API. If you send MongoDB instructions to make a modification and that actually does not change the current state of a matched document then `nModified` is returned as `0`. Not because the document "was not found", but simply because the current OP ( i.e `$addToSet` ) did not result in a change of state. Also even `nMatched` does not mean anything more than your query supplied simply did not find anything. Not errors. Don't treat them as such.

Comment: Hmm okay. I get where you're coming from. Maybe you want to add an answer with both of these explanations and we can close the question for good?

Comment: Maybe. But here's the general gist of it. If you are using a "widely used" library and then come across something you think should be done differently, then chances are that your presumption of action is not the correct one. Code libraries and things that have been around for while, ( you know, like databases ) behave in a certain way because people who used them already came to the consensus that the particular behavior is the best thing to do. So next time you hear hooves, think Horses and not Zebra's ( Unless you actually live in a locale where Zebras are common that is )

Comment: I get you. On another note, my attitude of having something opinionated strongly stems from the fact that I used I started building stuff with Spring-Boot/ROR and similar frameworks where there was a *set* way to do things. I struggled when I had to work with un-opinionated frameworks like Express at the start and rather 'open to interpretation' tools, in this regard, like MongoDB over something with rigid schemas like MySQL. Change is hard, but maybe change is good :)